# Transform $A\land B \Leftrightarrow B\lor A$ into conjunctive normal form

Tags: propositional-logic

How do I transform the following formula into conjunctive normal form?
$$
A \land B \Leftrightarrow B \lor A
$$

Comment: You could look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214338/how-to-convert-to-conjunctive-normal-form) for a start. Having said that, I'll add that here and elsewhere on SE, it's a good thing to include what you've tried, what you know, and where you got stuck. That way we'll be better able to gauge how to best answer your question. Finally, welcome to the site!

Comment: There must be hundreds of descriptions on the web and in textbooks of how to convert formulas to whatever normal form you can think of. There's no point in us writing yet another description of how to do that. If you have a conceptual question about some part of the process you don't understand, please ask about that. If you can't even get started, you need interactive help from your professor, tutor or TA and our question and answer format isn't suited to that.

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain how to transform $A \Leftrightarrow B$ into disjunctive normal form; your case is very similar. You start with a truth table:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
A & B & A \Leftrightarrow B \\\hline
F & F & T \\
F & T & F \\
T & F & F \\
T & T & T
\end{array}
$$
We now take all the lines in which the value is true, and for each of them construct the corresponding term. The line $F \; F$ contributes the term $\lnot A \land \lnot B$, and the line $T \; T$ contributes the term $A \land B$. Overall we get
$$ (\lnot A \land \lnot B) \lor (A \land B). $$
There is a similar algorithm to construct CNFs, which you must have learned in class. (It can also be found in many online resources.)

Comment: A minor quibble about your last sentence: experienced practitioners know one or more algorithms to generate a CNF expression, but in a teaching situation it's often common to show the DNF version (which is slightly easier from a conceptual perspective) and to either omit the CNF version or leave it as an exercise.

Comment: @RickDecker In that case there probably won't be an exercise about it.